# How to fetch data from controller with ajax request for looping inside table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, laravel, twig

Here is my html

```
<form method="get" name="form">
    <select name="grade" data-url="{{ path_for('get.student') }}">
        <option value="">-- Choose Grade --</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="myData"></div>
```

I want to display record based on option I choose with ajax request and put it into the table. Here is my route and controller for get request

```
$app->get('/', 'DataController:getStudent')->setName('get.student');

class DataController {
  public function getStudent($request, $response)
  {
    $grade = $request->getParam('grade');
    $student = Student::where('grade', $grade)->orderBy('name')->get();
    return $response->withJson([
        'result' => $student
    ]);
  }
}
```

and here is my script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form select[name="grade"]').on('change', function () {
            var url  = $(this).data(url);


            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'get',
                data = { grade: form.grade.value },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#myData').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't know if this is the right thing to do with ajax request. I just want to know how to fetch data object from controller and do the looping inside the table by myself. Please correct my way if this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You must have your JSON attribute `result` as HTML.

You have to create a Blade view such as `resources/views/students/grades.blade.php`, in this view you will render the table displaying grades for a student.

Then you render this view and send it through a JSON object.

The following is a pseudo code of it:

```
public function getStudent($request, $response)
{
    $grade = $request->getParam('grade');
    $data['student'] = Student::where('grade', $grade)->orderBy('name')->get();

    $table = view('students.grades', $data)->render();

    return response()->json(['result' => $table]);
}
```